Disable stoping the container after stop debuging in Pycharm
I set up the debugging for my Django app that is inside the docker container in PyCharm.
I did it with:

a new interpreter via Docker Compose
created the new run configuration Django Server.

My settings are:

Interpreter: new docker-compose interpreter
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 8000

All work well (start docker container in the terminal, start debugger - it works)
BUT:
When I click the stop debugger, this stops my docker container.
How to set it to not stop - so I can use it as a "normal" development container? (And that I don't need to restart it every time)

Do you use detached mode? docker-compose up -d

Yes,... in terminal I start containers like this
docker compose -f docker-compose.dev.mac.yml up -d

Seems like it depends on some parameters in Run > Edit Configurations->Docker->Docker Compose -> Stop Container

Can you elaborate more? Where is this function?
